# WooCommerce REST API: Gateway does not support admin changing the payment method on a Subscription

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am using [WooCommerce Subscription REST API](https://prospress.github.io/subscriptions-rest-api-docs/) to extend the subscription of the user. The problem that I have is that when I want to update expire time I get this error:

```
  Gateway does not support admin changing the payment method on a Subscription
```

Does someone know where is the problem?

I am using the following code to update the subscription expire time:

```
   return $this->guzzleClient->request('PUT', 'wp-json/wc/v1/subscriptions/'.$id, [
        'json' => [
            'end_date' => $endDate->toDateTimeString(),
            'status' => 'active',
        ]
    ]);
```

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into a similar issue. Instead of passing the whole subscription object back, we instead only passed the necessary information (in our case we wanted to add to the `coupon_lines` field).

Our resulting payload looked like:

```
{
  coupon_lines: [
    {
      code: "sample-code",
      amount: "10.00"
    }
  ]
}
```